# Sharepoint Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: css, browser-compatibility

I want to ENABLE horizontal scrolling. I have no idea where it went. I understand that SP uses a fluid layout, but when I make the browser's window smaller, the horizontal scrollbar is nowhere to be found. Eventually the fluid width stops and you start to loose visibilty on the right side of the page.

Any ideas?

Anybody have any CSS for body, .v4master, s4-ca, s4-workspace

that allows for horizontal scrolling? perhaps i had modified one of these

Comment: I've noticed this happen on particular browsers at time (Chrome) and also noticed that my Editor pane has kept on growing each time I edit a part...

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you changed the overflow of s4-workspace to possibly hidden? Are you seeing this problem with all browsers?

Comment: no unfortunately not. i've been digging around, thinking that either I had or something was overriding it.

Comment: All all browsers seeing this scrolling issue? The primary scrolling of the page is handled by the s4-workspace div, but I could see if that one of the other primary children container divs is hidding its overflow then the s4-workspace would not need scrollbars.

Comment: hi @EricOverfield   am having the same issue, as you mentioned s4-workspace, is hidden.what should i do to resolvbe this overflow horizontal scroll bar issue? pls help

Answer (score 0):

had to write some javascript to override SP's javascript for the s4-ca div.

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem. Can you share how you fixed this?

Comment: @NathanDeWitt I would if I could, but this is 4.5 years ago and unfortunately I don't work with Sharepoint any more. I do, however, specialize in front-end development, so if you can provide a URL that is accessible I can glance it over and perhaps provide some assistance

Comment: Thanks Rob. I asked before I realized how old the question was.